# Justification in table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

How to justify a table column like:

```
\begin{table}{j j}
ab cd & ef gh\\
ij kl & mn op
\end{table}
```

where `j` stands for justified column, i.e. both right and left are aligned.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

A simple readymade solution is to use *David Carlisle'*’s [tabulary](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/tabulary)-package. As a free bonus, you can specify the width of the tabular, and the width of the column is tailored to the width of the text.

The J-column gives you justified columns. You can also fine tune the appearance with the lengths `\tymin` and `\tymax` controlling the minimum and maximum widths of the columns, see the [manual](http://ftp.fagskolen.gjovik.no/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabulary/tabulary.pdf) page 4.

A MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabulary}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabulary}{.3\linewidth}{JJ}\toprule
  ab cd ... & ef gh ...\\
  ij kl ...& mn op ...\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to specify a fixed-width column, like `p{<len>}`, where `<len>` is a known TeX length. For example,

```
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{5cm}}
  ab cd ... & ef gh ... \\
  ij kl ... & mn op ...
\end{tabular}
```

Note that I use `tabular` and not `table`. The former is the structure to create the table, while the latter is a float that allows the structure to move around in your document.

Another alternative would be to place the contents of the cells inside a "justified" box, like a `\parbox`. However, this also requires you to specify the width:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \parbox{4cm}{ab cd ...} & \parbox{5cm}{ef gh ...} \\
  ij kl & mn op
\end{tabular}
```